# Formulario con HTML, JavaScript, Ajax y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

El objetivo de esta práctica consiste en que el usuario debe introducir los datos en un pequeño **formulario**, el cual desde desde **JavaScript** utilizando **ajax**, cogerá y los enviará al archivo **php** el cual se encarga de realizarla conexión con la base de datos de **MySQL** (en mi caso con **XAMPP**) y insertarlos en su respectiva tabla.
El problema está en que cuando relleno los datos y los envío, no se introducen en la base de datos ni tampoco me dice nada por consola, entonces quería saber como solucionar el fallo. Gracias de antemano.

Código **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="info">
        <p>Nombre:</p>
        <input type="name" name="nombre" id="nombre">
        <p>Correo:</p>
        <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo">
        <p>Tlf:</p>
        <input type="tel" name="tlf" id="tlf">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
<script src="conexion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código **JavaScript (JQuery)**:

```
$( document )
.ready( function ( ) {
    $( "#enviar" )
    .click( function ( ) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "insertar.php",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            data: $( "#info" ).serialize( ),
            success: function ( respuesta ) {
                alert( "Perfecto, los datos se han enviado correctamente!" );
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Código **PHP**:

```
<?php

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contra = "";
$db = "formulario";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contra,$db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error en la conexión";
    exit();
}

echo "Conexión establecida correctamente.";

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$tlf = $_POST['tlf'];

$sql = "INSERT into usuarios (nombre,correo,tlf) values ('$nombre','$correo','$tlf')";
echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: Ni en javascript ni en PHP muestra ninguno de los mensajes anteriormente descritos en el código? (a propósito... la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es una  cabecera de respuesta, no tiene ningún sentido enviarla al servidor en la petición)

Comment: A ver @Pipe, primero que nada, si no pongo el `headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },` me salta el error del CORS, y segundo, no me muestra ningún mensaje al ejecutarse, por lo que no se donde puede estar el problema.

Comment: Error de CORS solo le debería salir si está accediendo a otro dominio (pero según su ejemplo solo accede a `insertar.php` lo que da a entender que es el mismo dominio), y el que elige que dominios permitir y que dominios no es el *servidor*, no el *cliente*. Si el cliente lo eligiera, no tendría ningún sentido, porque entonces el cliente podría elegir consultar cualquier dominio y ya.

Comment: Sin un error es muy complicado ayudar porque el error puede estar en mil partes. Que retorna el servidor si inspecciona la respuesta por developer tools -> network?
Asegurese de tener esto en el PHP para asegurarnos que está mostrando todos los posibles errores en el servidor: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); `

Comment: Cuando lo lanzo con el **Live Server** de visual studio code, me salta `http error 405` y por consola me muestra: `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated`. Pero cuando lo abro en local, sin ningún live server, no me muestra nada.

Comment: @Pipe sinceramente no puedes saber el fallo si no lo pruebas, si me haces el favor, copia el código que lo he dejado bien estructurado y se entiende perfectamente, lo pegas en tu editor y lo pruebas tardando menos de 2 min en hacer eso. Luego ya a ver si tu encuentras el fallo, pero es que sin probarlo es imposible.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica

```
 <form method="POST" id="info"> a  
 <form method="POST" action="" id="info">

 $( "#enviar" ).click( function ( ) { a 
 $( "#info" ).submit( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Elimina

```
headers: {
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
```

Cuando le des en enviar debes tener el devtool del navegador abierdo en la sección "red" allí debe mostrarte el listado de peticiones y por su puesto la petición a insertar.php, si no aparece, tu error esta en JS, si te aparece la petición revisa que te este respondiendo cualquier echo puesto allí, también revisa que la ruta sea exactamente esa, según lo que veo, el archivo JS de la petición se encuentra en la misma ruta que el .php

OJO: Al modificar las cabeceras que se envían, estas deben coincidir con las que responde "insertar.php", por tanto es mejor eliminarlo.

Siempre debes empezar con la estructura más simple y básica que se pueda, cuando funcione, vas adicionando el resto.